# How to include custom header files directory into rootfs using yocto

Tags: linux, yocto

I want to install a directory having subdirectories of header source files, into the rootfs in the path `/usr/include/`.

The files are not included in the image.

directory structure in recipe

```yaml
maindir
 -subdir
   -headerfile1.h
   -headerfile2.h
 -subdir2
  - headerfile3.h
  - headerfile4.h
```

recipe.bb file:

```
SRC_URI += "file://maindir/"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_install () {
        
        install -d ${D}${includedir}/
        mkdir   -p ${D}${includedir}/maindir/
        mkdir   -p ${D}${includedir}/maindir/subdir/
        #I can see only an empty directory gets installed with no sub-directories and header files.
        cp -r ${WORKDIR}/maindir/ ${D}${includedir}/

        install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/maindir/subdir/* ${D}${includedir}/maindir/subdir/
}

FILES_${PN} += "${includedir}/maindir/"
```

How could I achieve this? Do I need to use `FILES_${PN}-dev` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need three things:

1. To install the *new* directories with subdirectories into target root filesystem —notice it is only for the new directories. This is done with `install -d ${D}<path in rootfs>`
2. Copy your header files into them. This is the `install -m <files mode> <source dir>/*.h ${D}/<destination>` syntax. Permission mode 0644 for header files, as they don't need execution permissions, only read only, unless you want to edit it as a super user, that is the 6 from the previous mode.
3. Extend `FILES` for packaging your files to a given package.

In summary, to accomplish the three steps in a syntactically correct way, you would:

```bash
do_install () {
  install -d ${D}/${includedir}/maindir
  install -d ${D}/${includedir}/maindir/subdir
  install -d ${D}/${includedir}/maindir/subdir2

  install -m 0644 ${S}/maindir/subdir/*.h ${D}/${includedir}/maindir/subdir/
  install -m 0644 ${S}/maindir/subdir2/*.h ${D}/${includedir}/maindir/subdir2/
}

FILES_${PN}-dev += "\
  ${includedir}/maindir/subdir/*.h \
  ${includedir}/maindir/subdir2/*.h \
"
```

Notice, it is good practice to use `<pkg name>-dev` with *-dev*, for packaging the headers files, nice catch!

Then, to install your just made recipe-dev package you do:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " recipe-dev"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was able to install the header files within the directories using the above solution.